# What is Janeu (Upnayan Sanskar)? What is the importance of it?

Tags: tradition

We believe that every religious tradition behind a scientific reason. What is the scientific reason behind this?

Why people of some caste wear it? I have asked some my Brahmin friends, they told me that this is a part of an education and it's a tradition, but am not satisfied with those answers.

Comment: Asking for scientific reason is off-topic here. Also this question is a duplicate of [What is the significance of the janeva (sacred thread)?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/418/what-is-the-significance-of-the-janeva-sacred-thread) and  [Why do some of the Hindu “Brahmins” wear a sacred thread?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/763/why-do-some-of-the-hindu-brahmins-wear-a-sacred-thread)

Comment: To community: We do have 3 questions related to 'Janeu', and two of them provide the same scientific reasons for hanging Janeu over the ear by different people. One in this answer and the other [here](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/763/why-do-some-of-the-hindu-brahmins-wear-a-sacred-thread/803#803). Reconsider **science off-topic** reason...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upnayan(Janeyu) tradition  is the part of an education procedure, which provides to a child at a particular age, it is also part of upbringing of Child, it is known as Upnayan Sanskar.

In it a person assume(hold) a janeu(a thread three-fold) there are three knots in it which is mark of three chief Gods of Hindu's Bramha,Vishnu And Mahesh.

It was wore by every cast people at that time when only 4 casts existed in hindu Bramhin, Kshatriya, Vaishya and Shudra. The tradition is made by our sages.

---

There are both scientific and Religious reasons behind it

**Religious reason**

One feels steady that the god always with me in form of *Janeu*, I am the offspring of god.
*Janeu*  symbol of god existence with holder(who holds *Janeu*) which inspires a man to avoid misdeeds.

**Scientific Reason**

When a man goes for urine or latrine ,he hangs and folds *Janeu* over the right ear

There is a blood vessel named *Lohitika* on right ear, it is pressed by *Janeu*, it helps to release urine or latrine freely and reduces the diseases related to them.

[image]

Comment: Any English name for Lohitika? Also is there a citation for the scientific reason?

Comment: THIS ANSWER IS MASTERPIECE ITS BEYOND THE VEDA!

Comment: may I know why did you rolled back my edit?

Comment: @Hardik Vyas: You should consider posting this answer to the other question as Bharat mentioned since it is a duplicate. This is on-hold because it is a duplicate, but you have option to give this scientific reason as the answer of other question [here](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/418/what-is-the-significance-of-the-janeva-sacred-thread). (science is not an off-topic in answers here:)) Also it will be better, citing the source for this reason.