# What is meaning of wearing yagopavita and its disposal techniques

Tags: rituals

I was initiated with yagopavita 2 years back, I was told it was required for performing rituals and to study the scriptures. Now I had(and still) have 2 questions in my mind -

> 1. What is meaning of wearing a yagopavita while many realized persons don't wear it ??

Scriptures can be studied without it, purity of rituals can be maintained without it, then Why should we wear yagopavita, just as fashion or there is more deep and more justified factual meaning ('other than keeping the body fluids intact while urinating' fact) to it.

Many yogis and great saints like Swami Vivekananda, Shri RamKrishna etc didn't wear yagopavita so I feel no necessity of it to become a yogi or to become realized with vedic knowledge.

Also if Shiva, Krishna ,& Rama are realized beings then why do they wear yagopavit they should drop it(or atleast should be potrayed to do so).

> 2. How to dispose it off without hurting environment and also without 
>      breaking vedic laws .

We have to usually change yagopavita within 4 months or atleast once a year and there are massive number of people who wear and throw it in a river or flowing water body saying `समुद्रम् गच्छ स्वाहा` 
meaning we are throwing it to go into ocean.

But in reality the water body is polluted by such acts, the thread is non-biodegradable and insoluble in water and it stays there for nearly 500 years, similarly if it is thrown out of water body it pollutes soil by mixing in it.

> So the wole point is If it is necessary to wear yagopavita then 
>   how and where should we dispose it off so that it can be done without 
>   hurting envrionment or without breaking or changing the rules of disposal.

Comment: First of all, scientific speculation is not allowed on this site.  If you want to ask what the religious reason for wearing it is, that would be more acceptable.  Also, personal advice questions aren't allowed on this site, so you should remove the part asking for an environmentally friendly way to dispose of it.  You can ask whether any scriptures discuss what the proper way to dispose of it is though.

Comment: Also, it seems like your question is partly a duplicate of these two questions: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/418/36 http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/763/36

Comment: No I don't think so

Comment: What's the difference between asking why we should wear it and asking what the significance of it is and why Brahmanas wear it?

Comment: I am confused as of to wear it or not because there are many people who don't and they are realized and many people who wear it do not follow the law of manu they eat non-veg and drink alcohol abuse , hurt and do many things like that plus I want to get to the real essence of wearing yagyopavita

Comment: Well, perhaps you should edit your question to focus on why some jnanis don't wear it.  You may be interested in this quote from the Brahma Upanishad: http://www.advaita.it/library/brahmaup.htm "The enlightened one should discard the external thread putting it off with the sacred tuft of hair on the head; the Supreme Brahman as the all-pervading one is the thread, and he should put this on."

Comment: I don't know about the thread but the upanishad is astonishing, truly experience based.. wonderful