# Why does Lord Vishnu also wear Yajnopaveeta in temples?

Tags: vishnu, temple, sri-vaishnava, yagnopavitam

Yajnopaveeta should be worn for doing vedic rituals. Why is it that Lord Vishnu is also adorned with yajnopaveeta in temples?

Comment: Question about Urdhvapundra is asked many times. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/12476/5212 Please limit question to Yajnopavitam to avoid duplicate closure.

Comment: related https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9567/12304

Comment: Why indeed :-)? For really understanding this, 1) You need to know what the "knots" in Yajnopaveetam signify. 2) How many set of Yajnopaveetam does He wear? Self-research suggested :-)