# Was Krishna's father Vasudeva a Brahmin?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, bhagavata-purana, brahmins

I have seen a image that Lord Krishna's father Vasudeva was wearing a sacred thread. Was Vasudeva a Brahmin or non-Brahmin?

Comment: Vasudeva was a Kshatriya and Nanda maharaja was a Vaishya king. I read it in Bhagavatham. I think in those days even kshatriyas and vaishyas used to wear the sacred thread. I don't know exactly but I remember I read it somewhere.

Comment: Yes all three varna's can wear the sacred thread. source- (http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2892/is-janeva-yaj%C3%B1opav%C4%ABtam-or-sacred-thread-limited-to-brahmins-only?rq=1)

Answer (score 3):

[Vasudeva](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vasudeva) was a Kshatriya king.

Sacred thread is meant for trai-varnikas (3-varnas) - Brahmana (scholars), Kshatriya(warriors), Vaishya(merchants), but not for 4th varna Shudras (workers)