# Which Kshatriya and Vaishya communities continue to wear the Yajnopavitam today?

Tags: practice, caste-system, yagnopavitam

We know from the [Manusmriti](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2892/is-janeva-yaj%C3%B1opav%C4%ABtam-or-sacred-thread-limited-to-brahmins-only/) that the first three Varnas (Brahmanas, Kshatriyas, and Vaishyas) are obligated to wear the Yajnopavitam.

Nowadays, it seems only Brahmins wear the thread and so it's even referred to as the "Brahmin thread".

So I'm wondering, are there any Kshatriya or Vaishya communities today who still wear it?

Comment: I know many Kshatriyas and Vaishyas who continue to wear Yagnopavitam. If it is referred only as a Brahmin thread, it is  wrong.

Comment: The thread for the Bramhanas are made of cotton and generally only cotton threads are available in the market so it is better known as Bramhin thread.

Comment: Ahh ok, what are the names of the communities?

Comment: @Ikshvaku There are no specific communities that I can list here. Its upto a person if he wants he can adhere to dharma.

Comment: @Sinister, could you tell which communities they belong to, or which part of India they live ?

Comment: @ram In the Telugu states, Vaishyas, Vishwa Brahmins(Carpenters, Jewellery makers) wear Yajnopavitam. They wear a different one than Brahmins. But many of them do not perform Sandhya rites. They only wear Yajnopavitam.

Comment: vishwabrahmins are not dwijas. They are the fourth varna.

Comment: arya vysya community from andrha @Ikshvaku

Answer (score 3):

The raju(Kshatriya) and komati(vysya) communities of andhra continue to wear sacred thread. The kammas are shudras and they do not wear

Answer (score 2):

Kamma Kshatriyas are still wearing in many areas. I have a friend from Kamma caste. He wears it. Kamma is a Telugu caste.

Comment: You can add some details or links that can provide further information about Kamma Kshatriyas.

Comment: Kammas are not kshatriyas. They are the fourth varna. Historically, kammas are said to have come into being only about 200-250 years ago and are a result of inter-mixing of two castes.

Comment: @moonstar2001 Yes, Kammas are not Kshatriyas. They are mixture of two castes. There are profession people in Kamma caste. Like Kamma kapu, Kamma sheshti etc., They came into existence during the Kakatiya period.

Comment: @Sinister what was your previous avatar? They are not that ancient AFAIK. came much later than kakatiyas.

Comment: @moonstar2001 Kammas came from Reddys. A sect of Reddys who are Soldiers and Senathipathis separated into different sect. A Reddy King searched for "Kamma" (ear ring of his mother) and he established Kamma sect..