# Color of Yagnopvaita (Janeu)

Tags: dharma-shastras, yagnopavitam

[Yagnopavitam](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/418/what-is-the-significance-of-the-janeva-sacred-thread) or Janeu is [generally worn as a white cotton thread amongst brahmins](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/20344/489), but some people wear yellow-colored thread (by applying turmeric).

I have following questions

1. What is the correct color of yagnopavitam?
2. Is it acceptable to wear yellow colored yagnopavitam?
3. Why do people generally wear white yagnopavitam, is it based on varna?

<sup>Note: I am expecting citations from Dharma shastras if possible.</sup>

Comment: Color not important some wear saffron colored also.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan "If eternal truth goes against the moral sensibilities of modern society, then there is something wrong with modern society" Nailed it, Good one.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Yeah that's why I asked this question as some consider it inauspicious for person (whose father is alive) to wear white thread.

Comment: Actually there used to be a cloth which was twisted. Now they keep threads as. A symbolic way. All colors are good. Plus one is advised to make own thread with measurement using.his fingers and do the ritual. But people purchase ready made

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Yeah it's really nice to make it yourself, but many people including me don't know the procedure for making thread so in my case I pay entrusted bramhana to make it for me.

Comment: If you wish i will try to share the process. One.has to chant his name and gotra while making. Hence its not right that some pundit give their thread to someone after wearing it.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi That'd be really nice if you can share the procedure.

Comment: Do you know about veda and shakha roughly

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Yup I do the abhivadanam part in Sandhyavandanam with those 'rough' details since I don't know my rajarishi pravaras, fyi I have tried online resources but they are so complicated and poor quality that the procedure is not revealed correctly.

Comment: @Yogi i think different shakhas have different length. I will share one link and video . though e.mail is better ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70012/discussion-between-rakesh-joshi-and-yogi).

Comment: I think in art of living upnayan vidhi, they give yellow janeu

Answer (score 7):

> What is the correct color of yagnopavitam?

None of the Smritis that i have read (except UsAna Smriti ) mention colors. Only thing they mention is the material which the threads are to be made of. And, these materials do vary with varnas.

> Manu Smriti 2.44. The sacrificial string of a Brahmana shall be made
>   of cotton, (shall be) twisted to the right, (and consist) of  three
>   threads, that of a Kshatriya of hempen threads, (and) that of a Vaisya
>   of woollen threads.

And, the same is stated in other Smritis as well.

The only Smriti that talks about a color is the UsAna Smriti (which is one of the 18 major Smritis as per the Yajnavalkya Smriti):

> Formerly, cotton-made sacred thread was instituted by Brahma. 
>   Strings of three threads are for the A Brahmanas. hempen cord for a [
>   Kshatriya] and ; a woolen one, a [for Vais'ya]. (6)
>
> **A  twice-born one** should always wear the sacred thread and tie up the
>   tuft of hair on his crown. **He should put on a most excellent white 
>   piece of cotton or silk cloth without any hole**, but quite different
>   from* the one used before.
>
> **UsAna Smriti's Chapter 1.**

Note that, what it says is formerly (that is prior to UsAna's time) the sacred threads were made for different varnas out of different materials. But now (that is during UsAna's time) the threads for all Dvija varnas are to be made of white cotton/silk only. Now, this makes lot of sense, because nowadays everyone use (mostly) white cotton threads only, irrespective of varnas.

Comment: Nice info/answer but this is not answering the question (I've updated question body).

Comment: @Yogi It is answering the Q. 1. No colors specified in most scriptures (only material specified). 2 White for all varnas is prescribed in one scripture. 3. Whether yellow is allowed or not is something that's not found in scriptures. So, better to wear white.

Comment: Yagnopavita dharana mantra has the word 'shubhra', if that indicates anything for white color then this might answer all of the questions easily.

Comment: Which mantra? and yes Shubra means white. The Usana Smriti also states it should be white for all 3 varnas. Why are u looking for that yellow thing? @Yogi

Comment: You have Usana Smriti?

Comment: Yes I have it. @SparkSunshine

Comment: @Rickross In hard format or soft format?

Comment: Its a PDF which has many other Smritis. I forgot from where I downloaded. Its downloaded years back. @SparkSunshine