# Among castes eligible to wear yagnopavitam, do different castes/sub-castes wear different kinds of Yagyopavitam?

Tags: caste-system, yagnopavitam

Do scriptures prescribe how the yagynpavitam should be made (number of threads, knots etc.)?

Comment: Related or possible duplicate [Color of Yagnopvaita (Janeu)](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22645/color-of-yagnopvaita-janeu)

Answer (score 1):

Use of word "Caste" when talking about Hindu scriptures is very confusing. There are Varnas (based on gunas) and Jatis n gothras (based on bloodlines), caste as a concept doesn't exist in scriptures.

According to Agamas, yagnopavita is the same for all, it changes based on certain attributes depending on the level of consciousness for the people wearing it.

Shaiva Agamas describes how many threads an individual has to wear based on his/her Sadhana. Any one can be initiated in to wearing Yagopavitha provided the individual adheres to certain required practices.

Comment: @Akhil- You omitted saying that it is for only savarna dvijas and the number of threads changes per ashrams of life.

Comment: If by Savarna Dvijas == all 4 Varnas then yes. I had people  "educate" me it's only 3 not 4. To them I point out the incidents in Ramayana where folks were doing SadhyaVandanam in "Sudra huts".

Comment: show me even a single shastra pramana making shudras eligible for upanayana sacrament...do not give anecdotes from Treta Yuga..what is binding on Hindus is Shruti Smriti and dharma shastras NOT anecdotes..

Comment: @Akhil- if all varnas are eligible for sacred thread, why in Tamil Nadu the shudras make such a song and dance about savarnas wearing their sacred threads.?