# Rules to be followed for wearing the Sacred thread / Janeu

Tags: rituals, brahmins, customs, yagnopavitam

What are the rules that one must observe to wear the **Yagnopaveetham** ? Would prefer if appropriate text is also quoted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Janeva (Yajñopavītam or sacred thread) limited to Brahmins only?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2892/is-janeva-yaj%c3%b1opav%c4%abtam-or-sacred-thread-limited-to-brahmins-only)

Answer (score 1):

Rules for for Wearing "Yagnophaveedham" or "License" to perform Homa or sacred ritual :-) all you need is the following Manthra.

1)   *Aachamanam: Shuklaam Bharadharam Vishnum etc.* (google please )
     if you utter this while holding small portions of water in right hand and consume it 
     you purify your internal body parts is the belief. if you do "Prokshanam" by 
     throwing that small portion of water all around you. That circle in which you sit 
     becomes pure as well...

2)   *Om Bhoo,bhuva,suvaha thatsavitur varanyam bhargo devasya dhe mahi dheyoyonah prachodyadh. Om Mapoh jyothiraso amrithambrahma Bhoorbhavaswarom* (The Gayathri + 3 Vyahruthi Mantra ( Inhale) + Jyothirasa mantra(exhale))

For meaning.. Refer to http://creative.sulekha.com/the-mantra-tantras-of-tsv-breath-control-pranayama_524013_blog

3. Sankalpam ( Resolve) : 
   *Mamo partha samastha duritha kshya dwara sri parameshwara preethyartham
   Sroutha smartha vihitha sadachara  nithya karmaanushtanaa yogyatha sidhyartham  brhma 
   teja abhivrudyartham yagnopaveetha dharanam karishye.*

To say you are  hereby going to wear by with sins/dangers eliminated, as per the liking/will of Parameshwara, the smartha lineage(followers of Guru Shankara), in all good tradition, for acheiving Capability for following everyday mandatory action (like Sandhyavandhana - to take care for your birth obligations), Betterment of existing "Brahma Tejas" that you are born with so that you become radiant like Brahma :-) I hereby  wear  Yagnopaveetham!

4) Now the actual Manthra to wear "one" yagnopaveetham (each with three strands)
   Hold by both hands, the brahmagranthi(Brahma's knot) in the poonal 
   being held above by the right hand facing upwards, the bottom portion hed by the left 
   hand dipped in the water container that you used to purify yourself with...
   Say the following *italicised* manthra and wear it!

*Yagnopaveetha  dharana maha manthrasya*

Here is the Yagnopaveetha dharana Great Mantra...

*Parabrahma rishihi*

The Rishi who initiated this is ParaBrahman himself - Touch forehead

*Trushtup chandhah*

Using Trishtubh metre unlike Anushtubh metre which refers to mantra intonation 
   intervals, (google) - touch below nose.

*Paramathma devatha*

The Supreme Atman that resides in the cavities of your heart - touch heart

*Yagnopaveetha dharane viniyoga*
    Getting ready to wear...

5)   *Yagnopaveetham paramam pavithram  prajapathe,
      Yat sahajam purasthad aayushyam Agriyam prathi muncha shubram yagnopaveetham 
      balamasthu theja.*
      Say above manthra and...Wear it. Across from Left shoulder to right side...
      Figure out the meaning yourself for above verse. It goes like "Yagnopaveetham is 
      Supremely pure, Prajapathi ..."

Now, You wore it. Cool ! now you are twice-born! Yes, it is said that it is like a second birth. Your dad typically initiates you and he does Brahmoupadesam...How to keep it with power? Utter 10 Gayathri's per day everyday..That is supposed to protect you. There are thrice-born Yagnopaveetha dharana as well not required unless you go as a sannyasin....