# Why have six threads after marriage in Yagnopaveetham (Poonal or Janeu)?

Tags: rituals, practice

As a follow-up to [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/418/what-is-the-significance-of-the-janeva-sacred-thread), why does the number of threads in Yagnopaveetham increase to six after marriage? Does it also increase with each child born?

Are these guidelines present in our scriptures? It will be helpful if you could cite them.

Comment: local custom only.

Answer (score 1):

Namaste

Threads in janeyu are indicative of number of debts that one has to clear prior to his soul ascendance to higher planes.  The threads do not increase by proportionate number of children.  A thread represents a child and there is no further counts on that parameter

Nowadays, apart from parents, there is "godfathers" / "godmothers", step mother, foster sons....etc..

Answer (score 0):

The sacred thread and its strands has nothing to do with number of wives or children etc.  Nor they are worn for someone else.

Usually the thread is given during the thread ceremony which is of three strands. This marks the beginning of the studies in the brahmacharya ashrama.

Later, after the completion of Vedic studies in the gurukula, the person finally graduates. The graduation is the completion of vedic studies and is marked by the ceremony, a samskara called as Samavartana.

Here the student is given six strand threads as he has completed the vedic studies.