# Why didn't Lord Ram try to prove Mother Sita's Purity but rather chose to exile her?

Tags: ramayana, rama, dharma, sita

- Lord Ram exiled Mother Sita to follow his Raja Dharma as his peoples doubted Mother Sita's Purity.
- Many of the people other than Lord Ram and Lakshmana witnessed Mother Sita's **Agni Pariksha**
- **King Sugreeva,King Vibishana and Entire Vanara army** witnessed the Agni Pariksha or Agni Pariksha can be again performed.
- Those people's can be used to Prove Mother Sita's Purity.
- Banning a women who didn't commit any **Sin** is **Adharma**.

**QUESTION :**

- Why didn't Lord Ram try to prove Mother Sita's Purity rather exiled her ?
- Why Lord Ram accepted and followed People's doubt as it was **not True and was Adharma** ?

Comment: Think it that way proving Maa Sita's chastity includes questioning her chastity first.

Comment: "Banning a women who didn't commit any Sin is Adharma". You are directly saying it is Adharma. Adharma according to whom? You should say that also. Who banned? He was following Raja Dharma. As a king people's wish comes first and then himself or the family.  "Agni Pariksha can be again performed." Who performed Agni Pariksha? Rama didn't order Sita to perform her chastity. There was no need to prove anything to the people. Eama never had doubts on Sita.

Comment: @SreeCharan friend if you blame your classmate that he stole your money(your doubt )  and if your teacher punish him accepting your doubt and one day you find that it is wrong then is it dharma or adharma ? To say simply punishing one who didn't commit sin is what dharma or adharma?

Comment: This is actually duplicate of [Why did Sri Rama banish Lady Sita when he was a witness of her fire-test himself?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/343/3500). Padma Purana mentions the story behind that act.

Comment: @TheDestroyer friend it has many personal opinions and One or Two scriptural answers but they are also explaining why did he banished her and my question is very different from it if you compare both of them you can see it

Comment: @Sakthi - Thanks for accepting my answer and for bounty. The question is very good but meanwhile its very important too. This is mythological explanation why. Shree Rama took this decision ? But still I will improve the answer with other reasons from scriptures .OR from explanations given by Acharyas or Gurus etc. Thanks again .

Answer (score 12):

## Why-didnt-lord-ram-try-to-prove-mother-sitas-purity-but-rather-chose-to-exile her? was Adharma  ?

The exact answer why shree Rama sent Sita  on exile in the forest  and not again took her Agni Pariksha is given in [**Padma Purana**](http://gdurl.com/Tcco/download) – **Volume 5- PATALAKHANDA - Chapter No. 57 -The Washerman's Former Birth  . Page no. 1879 –Motilal _Banasirdass version.** The whole chapter is fully dedicated just for answering this question.

According to Padma Purana once  when Sita  was young and still unmarried was playing in the grove of her garden .She  heard the discussion of two parrots. about her and Shree Rama.

> **3-11** That pair, enjoying (each other's company), quickly flew in the
>   sky, settled on the lap of a mountain, and spoke (to each other): and
>   spoke (to each other): "On the earth, charming Rama will be the king.
>   His wife will be (a woman) by name Sita. The intelligent, powerful
>   king, vanquishing (his enemies), will rule (over eleven thousand
>   years. Blessed is that queen Janaki, and blessed the earth) along with
>   her for is he, named Rama, who having approached each other, will
>   gladly enjoy.

When the couple of parrots was conversing in this way, Sita understood that they are talking about her and realized that this is a divine couple. **She then said to her friends: ''Slowly catch this charming pair of the birds."** The friends just then went to the mountain, and caught the excellent pair of the birds. Then Sita asked them about what they were discussing. Who are they and two where they came from? Who is Rama, and who is
Sita? From where  did they got the information about them!! ?
The pair of birds said:

> **19-26**. There is a very great sage Valmiki who is the best among those who know dharma. That sage made his disciples sing the future
>   adventures of Rama. He, engrossed in the wellbeing of all beings,
>   everyday remembered its words. All those future adventures of Rama,
>   being sung repeatedly, were heard by both of us; they came to us (i.e.
>   were mastered by us) due to repetition. Listen to them. In the end we
>   shall tell who that Rama is and who that Janaki is and what will
>   happen to her with Rama of a playful nature. Glorious Visnu, good
>   stories about whom are sung by celestial women, will, having divided
>   himself into four, come up at the sacrifice performed by Rsyasrnga.
>   He, having a bow in his hand, will come along with Visvamitra and his
>   own brothers to Mithila. Then there seeing a bow difficult to be taken
>   (i.e. wielded) by other kings, he will break it, and will obtain the
>   very charming daughter of Janaka. O excellent one, we have heard that
>   with her he will rule over a large kingdom. O you of a beautiful body,
>   we who had flown there, heard this and other (things) about you, told
>   by those who lived there.

Then the pair of birds asked Sita to let them go where they are living.
Hearing these words, Janaki  reveled her identity and  said to them: I am that Janaki. the daughter of Janaka, which you are menrioning. And told them that  shall truly release you when that very charming Rama comes to me; not otherwise

> **41-53** Hearing these words they trembled and were frightened. They were mutually (i.e. both) afraid; (and) said this to Janakt: "O good
>   lady, we are birds, living in forests and resorting to trees. We
>   wander everywhere. We would not get happiness (merely by staying) at
>   home. **I am pregnant. Having gone to my place and having given birth to
>   sons (i.e. young ones) I shall come (back). I have told you the
>   truth."**

(Though) thus addressed by the female parrot, **Sita did not release her.** Then her husband (i.e. the male parrot), eager,
and with his face hung down spoke to her: "Sita, release my wife. My charming wife would be (i.e. is) pregnant. Having performed her (i.e. after her) delivery I shall come to you, .Thus,, addressed, Sita  said to male  parrot  "O you very intelligent one, you can gladly go. I shall keep this happy one, doing what is dear to me,' near me.

> **57-66**. Though admonished with various words, she did not release her. **The (parrot's) wife, who was angry, and miserable, then cursed
>   Janaka's daughter: "As you are separating me from my husband, in the
>   same way you will be, when pregnant, separated from Rama."** When she,
>   the afflicted one, was repeatedly saying like this, her life departed
>   due to misery, full of the distress of her husband. For her who was
>   repeatedly remembering Rama and uttering (the name) Rama, a divine car
>   properly arrived. The female parrot became luminous when she had gone
>   to heaven. When she died, her husband, that lord of birds, was
>   extremely angry, and being distressed, fell into Gariga: ''In Rama's
>   city, full of people, I will be born as (a sjjdra so) that due to my
>   words she will be dejected, and extremely unhappy due to separation
>   (from her husband)." Saying so, he who was distressed, angry,
>   frightened and shaking due to separation  from her, fell into the
>   water of Ganga graced with eddies. Due to his being angry, due to his
>   being distressed, and due to his having insulted SIta, he obtained
>   very (mean) sudrahood (as he was born as) a washerman named Krodhana.
>   That best bird (or best brahmana) who, doing ill to the great,
>   abandons his life through anger, obtains sudrahood after he dies. That
>   took place. Due to the words of the washerman she was censured and
>   separated. On account of the curse of the washerman, she was separated
>   (from Rama), and she went to the forest.
>
> ---

---

> Conclusion – So from this story of Padama Purana ,we come to know
>   that  Sita faced exile in the forest and separated from Shree Rama
>   while she  was pregnant because of curse of divine Parrots. And just
>   because of the curse  Lord Ram didn’t try to prove Mother Sita's
>   Purity again by  Agani–Pariksha but  rather exiled her.  And after
>   all this was just divine  LEELA of Lord Vishnu’s avatara shree Rama so it’s
>   not considered  adharma cause we don’t fully understand divine
>   leelas.

Comment: Excellent finding! Never knew this part of Ramayana.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto - Yes , Padma purana ,Skanda Purana are large texts also mahabharata and they contain many stories.I also came to know most of the stories after reading :-).

Answer (score 4):

Rama never had any doubt. Even layman's doubt was already long-ago cleared by Agni Pariksha. People thinking it was some easy drama. Just put your hand on top of candle for 5 seconds, and see if you can bear it. Only people who have done agni pariksha themselves have right to comment about Sita devi or Draupadi (who does Agni snanam before entering house of other husband).

People keep on questioning all the time. These people will also question Rama as why he killed Vali from hiding. Vali himself asked Rama 6 questions, and after Rama satisfactorily answered, Vali gave his son Angada to Rama for guardianship. Still, even today, there is debate, because they don't listen to Ramayana upanyasam from elders fully.

**Rama wanted his wife who was garbhavati, to be under Rishi's care. Because during garbham, all good things must be heard by embryo/foetus.** And who better than Valmiki muni to impart this knowledge. And after they are born, Lava & Kusha learn Ramayana from Valmiki.

Also, as a king, and as Dharma incarnate (ramo vigrahavaan dharmah), he is not supposed to ignore his subjects, however varied their opinions might be.

So, as '2 mango with 1 stone', he sent Sita devi to Valmiki ashrama.

Comment: You should cite sources.

Answer (score 4):

**Shri RAma himself was not convinced to accept Sita at first, irrespective of whether she was chaste (pure) or not.**

And he was very much right in that. According to the *Dharma* [at least during RAmAyana times], a wife is not acceptable & ought to set free if another man takes her, for whatever reasons. Shri RAma was aware of this morality. Besides, abduction of Sita happened because of her own mistakes (sending RAma, sending Lakshmana, crossing *rekha*). Hence, after [killing RAvana](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20532/1049), he followed the same Dharma towards Sita irrespective of her purity.

This story is described as part of [MahAbhArata - Vana Parva](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03288.htm) by sage Markendeya to Yudhishtira:

> And having slain the Ten-necked Rakshasa, the lord Rama of worldwide fame, that conqueror of hostile cities, bestowed Lanka on Vibhishana. Then that old and wise counsellor (of Ravana) known by the name of Avindhya, with Sita walking before him but behind Vibhishana who was at the front, came out of the city. And with great humility Avindhya said unto the illustrious descendant of Kakutstha, '**O illustrious one, accept thou this goddess, Janaka's daughter** of excellent conduct!' Hearing these words, the descendant of Ikshwaku's race alighted from his excellent chariot and beheld Sita bathed in tears. And beholding that beautiful lady seated within her vehicle, afflicted with grief, besmeared with filth, with matted locks on head, and attired in dirty robes, **Rama, afraid of the loss of his honour, said unto her, 'Daughter of Videha, go withersover thou likest! Thou art now free!** What should have been done by me, hath been done! O blessed lady, owning me for thy husband, it is not meet that thou shouldst grow old in the abode of the Rakshasa! It is for this I have slain that wanderer of the night! **But how can one like us, acquainted with every truth of morality embrace even for a moment a woman that had fallen into other's hands? O princess of Mithila whether thou art chaste or unchaste, I dare not enjoy thee**, now that thou art like sacrificial butter lapped by a dog!'

Hence the discussion of RAma following common people's doubts & asking Sita to perform *Agni Pariksha* -- becomes moot. The morality of those times were not allowing such act (i.e. accepting Sita after being abducted by RAvana). Shri RAma was conversant with all truths of Morality & hence followed the scripture prescribed path.

---

The subsequent story states that how Sita, several deities & Brahma-deva himself asked RAma to accept Sita.

> Then the divine and pure-souled Brahma of four faces, that Creator of the Universe himself sprung from a lotus, showed himself on his car to Raghu's son. And Sakra and Agni and Vayu, and Yama and Varuna and the illustrious Lord of the Yakshas, and the holy Rishis, and king Dasaratha also in a celestial and effulgent form and on car drawn by swans, showed themselves ...
>   -- princess of Videha spoke ... 'O prince, I impute no fault to thee, for thou art well acquainted with the behaviour that one should adopt towards both men and women....  have never, even in my dreams, cherished the image of any other person, so be thou my lord as appointed by the gods.'
>   -- And the Wind-god was heard to say ...
>   -- And the god of Fire said, ...
>   -- And Varuna then said, ...
>   -- And Brahma himself then said, ... 'O son, in thee that art honest and pure and conversant with the duties of royal sages, this conduct is not strange. Listen, however, ... '

However, RAma was finally commanded by the soul of his father Dasaratha & he gladly accepted (again showing the reverence to his father, a proper following Dharma):

> -- Dasaratha said, 'I have been gratified with thee, O child! Blessed be thou, I am thy father Dasaratha! I command thee to take back thy wife, and rule thy kingdom, O thou foremost of men!'
>   -- Rama then replied, 'If thou art my father, I salute thee with reverence, O king of kings! I shall indeed, return, at thy command, to the delightful city of Ayodhya!'

Further story doesn't state of any *Agni Pariksha*. However, even if that had happened, that was not because *RAma* earlier thought Sita as chaste and then doubted due to public pressure. But that would have been due to a moral responsibility towards his citizens about proving the chastity of the queen, they revere.

Comment: I disagree with mistakes of Sita part. I don't think Rama ever blamed Sita for that. So those things should not be mentioned in this scenario.

Answer (score 3):

In the 45th Chapter of Uttara Khanda Sri Rama justifies the banishment of Seeta.  He mentions that his doubt on Seeta's chastity was cleared, when at the Agni Pariksha all the Devas and Gandharvas came along with Indra to proclaim Seeta's purity and hand her over to him.

The Incarnation of Sri Ramachandra was of Uttam Maryada Purusha - most superior man who follows the path of Dharma. Raja Dharma lays down that the king is not only the sustainer of his people, but is also governed by their desires.

The rumour about Seeta's character was demeaning both of them. No king should live with 'apakirti' - which was what Sri Rama and Seetaa Devi were being subjected to.  To escape from 'apakirti' Sri Rama was willing to give up even his own life - so why not Seeta (Uttara Kandha 45:14).

Sri Rama was on the horns of a dilemma - under Raja Dharma he had to satisfy his subject's reasonable demands. He was Maryada Purusha and as a king he could not co-habit with a woman whose chastity was in doubt. But as a husband who knew his wife was chaste and it had been proved to him, he could not forsake his wife at the whims and fancies of the public. [As Shakespeare wrote in 'Julius Ceaeser' Ceaser's wife should not only be pure but should also appear so - of some such words to the same effect]. Sri Rama chose to follow Raja Dharma, rather than give up his throne.

was this right / moral/ etc. is another separate question.

Comment: friend mother seeta was also a citizen of lord ram's rule and as a citizen of his rule lord ram should have tried to investigate and find the truth and clear the doubt of citizens and as a king lord ram should clear the doubts of citizens and reveal the truth.Isn't this also a duty of a King

Comment: Seeta Devi too undoubtedly was a citizen of Sri Rama's kingdom - as I mentioned earlier, whether Sri Rama's decision to follow Raja Dharma instead of Pati Dharma was right / moral is an unanswered question.  To the extent I have perused the Puranas and Ramayana in various languages -  this aspect has neither been covered nor mentioned.

Comment: Friend Are you saying that there is NO ANSWER to this question ?

Answer (score 1):

I feel people have misunderstood role of dhobi in ancient Vedic society. Meaning of agni parixa is not about chastity the way it is understood today but about a tapasvi's test. Ramayan is another version of the more ancient story in which Sati metaphorically burns her gross body desires in agni of tapas. Sita's agni parixa is the same. It is not about actually sitting in a real fire. Sita, like many others was a Mahisi who are main participants in yagyas. They had to do mantra siddhis which involved intense tapasya and so celibacy. Sita and Ram were not 'married' as we understand today. But paired up as ideal Mahisa and Mahisi. Mahisa were also defenders and fought when required. The two were the yin and yang and had to have perfect balance when doing yagyas. Pati meant leader and not husband like it does today. Sita had become highly advanced in tapasya and so it was decided that she would advance as a rushi, which too is for benefit for society. This is why she goes to ashram which was not orphanage. In those days there were no orphans since all children went to residential gurukuls together and were trained by rushis (without any prejudice). Later they were given posting (like in army) and mentored by seniors. Later even adults went for further education. Sita later took samadhi in pruthvi and this is only possible if a person is advanced tapasvi. Story makes sense if read as a case study of Sanatan Dharma and Yoga. Ancient Arya society was cashless and martial. Even dhobis were part of the govt. as mentioned in Mahabharat, and so carried weight. They were not merely servants. Nor was Manthara. Just like how a prime minister will employ highly educated advisors, not illiterate, dumb servants.
For example, Asvamedha was not about horses but about being done with the speed of a horse. Asva has been translated as sun, or Asvinau who were scientists and highly knowledgeable. Medha means essence, while Medhaa means wisdom. So yagya was about spreading wisdom and knowledge and entire nation.

Comment: So you mean that sita was not ever abandoned while pregnant ? I feel this incident is an interpolation in the text

Comment: The whole premise is wrong because authors didn't understand ancient life style of aryas. They were highly spiritual and this required constant tapasya. Sita was one of the panchkanya (see sloka), so not wife so not pregnant. She was Mahisi who participated in yagyas after attaining mantra siddhis. They were dharmic partners not husband-wife.

Comment: So who then knows better about rama And seeta ? Further doing tapas has nothing to do with not having kid or getting pregnant. In fact all the rishis were happily married and continued tapas. Please see my answer s on this forum about grihastham. Btw what do you mean by mahisi ? Mahisha means buffalo.

Comment: Mahisi does not actually mean buffalo (although many think so). Metaphors were used. So it could mean as strong as a buffalo. Mahisi and Mahisa were titles given to those who specialised in yagyas and did intense tapasya to make sure the mantras actually worked. For example, bringing rain etc.Rushis were NOT married, atleast not all the time. The word 'pati' meant leader,i.e.kulapati.Women on his team were not wives but trainees,yagya personell.Yoga+Bhoga can't go together.Sadhna+meditation basic reqd.for siddhi.Logical sequence.

Comment: I think you are strongly in favor of sanyasa which i strongly reject as a part.of vedic life. I am ready to provide references.for rishi and dAmpatya life if at all you would be interested. Or you can also participate in agama chat room here

Comment: Renunciation is something which can be practiced by all whether married or celibate. I am talking in context of Vedic rajas of Treta Yuga who were expected to be highly spiritual. There is a big difference between writing about it and actually practicing it. There are records of many yagyas being actually done by kings which went on for many months. A lot of ojas shakti, which is made from perservation of sukra gets used up. This can be done only by celibacy, then what is point of marrying?

Comment: Please see.my detailed answer of brahmacharya wrt vedas.  Yajnas should be done by all vedics wherever possible as per the capacity along with the spouse.

Comment: Brahmacharya is NOT celibacy. Can you explain how ojas is used during yajna ? A married man is still a brahmachari if he mates only on the prescribed tithis

Comment: Please do research of how sukra gets transformed to ojas shakti yourself, as I cannot provide tutorial on this forum. It is too lengthy. Try online by Swami Sivananda. Try to understand my point, that when in those days women accepted a rushi/raja as 'pati' the word translates as 'leader', in context of kulapati. Only in past few centuries the word is being used in Hindi to mean husband. If they were not husband then how could woman be spouse? Even Gujarati, Marathi etc. don't use 'pati' for husband. It helps to check sanskrit dictionary for etymology.

Comment: i am.not asking about semen to ojas because i have known it though ayurveda. Further why should pati be a leader or patNI be a leader. I feel both should be equal. It was just a request to you to go through some of my related answers. If you don't wish its fine too. Vedas advocate agni karya to all the.people.of bhArata irrespective of caste or gender.

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/18076/7853

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/17135/7853

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/17157/7853

Comment: I am telling you that synonym of the word pati is a leader. It is NOT about gender. In those days they spoke pure Sanskrit which is NOT like Hindi. You should try and understand the roles they do in society. For example today most of the leaders of army are men. Would you call that discrimination or just convinience due to level of physical exertion involved. Please try not to jump to conclusions. If you do not want to accept my explanation its okay.

Comment: ok pati means leader but whose leader ? Sita's leader was rama ? And also what was the relation among them if not husband and wife ?

Comment: Would like to refer you to my blog on speakingtree.in titled myth busters. Pls see that for your answers as per my understanding and research.

Comment: Interesting discussion, that I am raking up after a year. The theme presented in the answer is interesting, but I feel a few more details about the sources are required. Sona Parivraj's point taken.  Just two clarifications. During Satya Yuga and Treta Yuga, rishis could practice brahmacharya and gristha jeevan simultaneously, beccause the vedic precept and practice about sexual union were prescribed. Not only the days, but also the muhurthas for the same were prescribed.      continued

Comment: Continued:          Women had sex, only after their ritu snan meaning close to the time of ovulation. Sexual relations in those days were for the purpose of procreation. Regarding reference to the muhurtas, reference is drawn to Srimad Baghvad Purana where Kashyapa remonstrates his wife Diti " wait another muhurta - now is the time Shiva is wandering around with his ganas. Any union now will be unlucky for the unborn child" -  Diti was adamant, Kashyapa had thirteen wives, daughters of Daksha Prajapati. To maintain peace, Kashyapa had union with his wife Diti             Continued

Comment: Continued:    To maintain peace Kashyapa had union with his wife Diti, the twins born of this union were Hiranyaksha and Hiranyakahipu - and the rest as they say is history. So Rama and Sita could be Raja Rishis and husband and wife too. And Rama could impregnate Sita as permitted by Vedas.