# Why did Bhagwan Ram abandon Mata Sita?

Tags: ramayana

It is commonly known that Bhagwan Ram abadoned Mata Sita after returing to Ayodhya. And she had to live in forest.

I want to know the exact details as to why Ram abandoned Sita.

What did Ram say to Sita while ordering her to leave the palace and live in forest ?

I want to know it in detail.
From Valmiki Ramayan or from any Purans, Mahabharat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The details of Sita Devi's abandonment are mentioned in the Uttarakhand of Ramayana.

[Chapter 43 of Uttara-Kanda](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-ramayana-of-valmiki/d/doc424814.html), details the reason for Sri Rama's decision to exile Sita Devi from the kingdom.

> Thus exhorted by Raghava, Bhadra, with joined palms, in profound reverence, addressed that mighty hero in measured tones, saying:—
> “Hear, O King, what the people are saying, be it good or ill, in the highways, markets, streets, woods and parks—
> ‘Rama has achieved the impossible by throwing a bridge over the sea which to our knowledge was never done by his predecessors nor even by the Gods and Danavas together. With his foot-soldiers and cavalry, he has destroyed the invincible Ravana and has made the monkeys, bears and Rakshasas subject to him. Having slain Ravana in the fight and recovered Sita, Raghava, having mastered his anger, has taken his spouse into his house again. **What pleasure can his heart experience in possessing Sita, whom Ravana formerly held in his lap, having borne her away by force? How is it that Rama was not filled with aversion for her after she had been taken to Lanka and conducted to the Ashoka Grove, where she was left to the mercy of the titans? We shall now have to countenance the same state of affairs regarding our own wives, since what a king does, his subjects follow!’**
> “These are the sayings current everywhere among the people of town and country, O King.”

In Chapter 45, Sri Rama expresses his predicament to his 3 brothers and commands Lakshmana to take Sita Devi to Valmiki Ashrama.

> The Gods and Gandharvas testified to her pure conduct in Lanka, where Mahendra placed the proofs in my hand, further I knew from my own inner being that the illustrious Sita was innocent. It was then that I took her back and returned to Ayodhya. Since then a great sadness, on hearing the censure of the people of town and country, has filled my heart. Whoever it may be, if his ill fame be current in the world, he falls to a lower state, so long as the defamatory rumours exist. Dishonour is condemned by the Gods; honour is revered in the world and, it is on account of fair repute, that great souls act. As for me, so greatly do I fear dishonour that I would renounce my life and you yourselves on its account, O Bulls among Men, how much more therefore is it incumbent on me to separate myself from the daughter of Janaka. See therefore in what an ocean of grief I have fallen! There is no misfortune greater than this **Tomorrow, at dawn, O Saumitri, take my chariot with Sumantra as your charioteer and, causing Sita to ascend it, leave her beyond the confines of the kingdom.**

As ordered by Sri Rama, Lakshmana took Sita Devi's and left her at Valmiki's ashrama. The entire episode is covered from Chapter 45 through Chapter 48 of Uttara Kanda

So, Sri Rama didn't meet Sita Devi when she was taken away from the kingdom. She was not aware that she was exiled when Lakshamana approached her. Lakshmana took her on the pretext of visiting the sacred retreats of the banks of the Ganges, which she had asked Sri Rama a while ago.

The exact answer as to why Sri Rama exiled Sita Devi to the forest and not again take her Agni Pariksha is given in Padma Purana (Volume 5/ Patala Khanda/Ch# 57) or you can check [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/20495/3745).