# Panchakacham purpose

Tags: rituals

Anybody knows the reason behind why brahmans or few other community people wear panchakacham. I am looking for a spritual or a scientific reason than quoting, its easy to do pooja etc. What is also the purpose of wearing uthariyam. what are the rules to be followed while wearing it. Can any body respond to this kindly.

Comment: Duplicate of http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/418/3500

Comment: @TheDestroyer pancha kaccha is not yaknopavitam...

Comment: Non-Brahmins and even non-Hindus wear uthariyam. I don't think it is a Shastric practice.

Answer (score 1):

In Vedic tradition, we come across the highly recommended dressing attire for men called-Pancha Kacham. What is its significance that makes it imperative for every man belonging to Vedic SampradhAyam to comply with this requirement once he gets into wedlock? 
Pancha Kacham  is specifically prescribed only  for “Gruhasthas” belonging to all the four Varnas. Until a man enters Gruhasthashrama,  he is a Bachelor (BrmachAri) focusing on gathering knowledge through appropriate education without yielding to any sensual pursuits. A VAnaprastha and a Sanyasi are expected to lead the lives of pure ‘Nivruthi’ Dharma–giving up the worldly desires (Pravruthi Dharma) adopting spiritual pursuit.  So, that makes the Gruhastha eligible for true Pravruthi Dharma that allows him to get married, have children, earn Aishwarya and so on. While doing so, he is expected to discharge his karmic duties in compliance with the Shastras.
As the human body is made of PrAkruthic matter of 3 gunas that are the sources of Pancha bhoothas, Pancha TanmAtras, Pancha Karma Indriyas and Pancha GyAna Indriyas and Manas, it is necessary to keep them under control by following Niyamas-AnushtAnas prescribed in the Shastras with respect to AhAram and Vastra DhAranam. The aim is to maximize Satva guna keeping the other two gunAs (Rajas & Tamas) low. The dress code Pancha Kacham is designed to enable a Gruhastha to develop in him the right attitude towards Pravruthi Dharma when worn along with Kaupeena and Anga Vastra (Uthirium). ﻿
Madisaar is the equivalent dress code for the married women as Pancha Kacham for Gruhasthas.The Sanskrit word “Pancha” means ‘Five’ and the word “Kacham” literally means “Tie-up”. The dress code Pancha Kacham simply enables to keep the Prakritic bodily elements tied up and under control! Once these elements are in control the wandering Manas  gets stabilized into SAtvic Buddhi. Once SAtvic nature begins its ascent, the other two unwanted gunas start their descent.
A man is considered qualified for Gruhastha Ashrama when he successfully trains himself as a Brahmachari learning the Tatva, Hita and Purushartas of life and decides to launch himself in the worldly duties of Dharma (complying with Shastras), Artha (earning all kinds of wealth) and KAma ( sensual pleasures). These three pursuits are known as ‘Pravruthi Dharma’. That leaves the pursuit of Moksha Dharma which is also known as ‘Nivruthi Dharma’ as the option for all the VarnAshrama followers.
VarnAshrama Dharma needs to be followed by all the 3 KaranAs-Manas, Word and Action.﻿

Answer (score -1):

Panchakatcham means 5 edges or knots.

This represents 5 indriyas or senses which these organs generate.

Thus, during puja or rituals this is worn as symbol to control the five senses so that there will be the intent focus.

This is only symbolic and thus ignites the consciousness.

As we have dress pattern for various occasions like to office, to school or any marriage. This pattern is for making the body and soul pure while praying.